# SQL Server duplicating data

Tags: c#, sql-server

My program using C# is duplicating all data stored in SQL Server; what is wrong with the `if` statement below?

```
if (input.StartsWith("H") && input2.Equals("01"))
{
    conn.Open();
    comando.CommandText = "INSERT INTO data(id, name, time) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', GETDATE())";
    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    textBox1.Clear();
}

if (input.StartsWith("H") && input2.Equals("02"))
{
    conn.Open();
    comando.CommandText = "INSERT INTO data(id, name, time) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', GETDATE())";
    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    textBox1.Clear();
    textBox2.Clear();
}
else
{
    //do nothing
}
```

Comment: What happens when you debug? What are the values in `input2`? Please do not use string concatenations for constructing sql queries (SQL Injections) and as it is the same query you can join the two `if statements`

Comment: Both sql statements are the same...

Btw, take a look at parametrized queries to avoid SQL injection

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **never EVER** concatenate together your SQL statements like this - ***ALWAYS*** use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicates, you can add check if the id already exists by using if exist statement. Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Put primary key constraint on Id column and also check exists if Id is available. If yes, then update else insert.

You can make your query like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM data WHERE Id = '" + textBox1.Text + "')
   UPDATE data 
   SET name = '" + textBox2.Text + "', time = GETDATE()
ELSE
   INSERT INTO data (id, name, time) 
   VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', GETDATE())
```

I did not test whether it works, but you can use it as reference.

But yes make this query parameterize query to avoid SQL injection like other people said. You can see below links how to make your query as parametrize query:

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Parameterized-Queries-ADO.Net.aspx

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx

I hope it will help you. :)